# Create a closed polygon from a series of edges given a point

Tags: c#, sharpmap

I have a series of points fed into a voronoi graph class that returns a series of edges defining the bounds between these points, the process works it returns a series of edges.

I now need to do a ray/fill using the points and these edges to build polygons around each point.... for the life of me I can't seem to figure out a process of doing this or a code sample...
C# code or thought process would be great .... maybe ray collision?

[image: Sample Voroni]

Comment: Are you doing this in straight C#, or are you using a library like ArcGIS? Does the process not return any other information than the edges?

Comment: I've used http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/fortunevoronoi.aspx class it return a series of edges with left and right nodes, this is being done in c# with the sharpmap library, I only have the point information available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [**PolygonBuilder** in nettopologysuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/source/browse/branches/v2.11/NetTopologySuite/Operation/Overlay/PolygonBuilder.cs?spec=svn520&r=478)

> NetTopologySuite is a C#/.NET port of JTS Topology Suite, a Java library for GIS operations, (OpenGIS compliant).

Comment: I think I've got an idea for this particular set of data if I draw a line from each node to the center of each edge the edges that have only 1 intersection are the ones that create a closed polygon.... might not be the prettiest routine but it will get the job done... or else I will look into NetTopologySuite

Answer (score 1):

Does [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/lines-to-polygons) help?

Comment: That question is apt.  The point hinted at by @Anthony in a comment to the question is that one shouldn't have to go to such lengths: any procedure to compute Voronoi polygons already "knows" the topology and ought to be able to communicate it directly to the caller.

Comment: Exactly. If you have the reference to the left and right nodes, you should just be able to create polygons by finding all the edges for a specific node, i.e. using the soltion for the question above.