# Batch create curved polyline in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, geometry, curvature

How can I batch create curved linear features i.e. using 3 points in ArcPY?

The real question is, whether we can create curved linear feature through arcpy or we have to use ArcObjects! Because, to me, it seems we can not do that in ArcPy.

to create linear (non-curved) features we can use:

```
arcpy.Polyline(Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in feature])))
```

This question is a duplicate of [Generating true curve elliptical polygons in file geodatabase using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66551) New comers, note that curves are only supported on 10.3 and above. see [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Geometry_objects/02r3000000n1000000/)

Comment: Is there any chance that the loophole that crmackey exploits at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66551/generating-true-curve-elliptical-polygons-in-file-geodatabase-using-arcpy may be useful to you?  If so, this may be a duplicate.

Comment: True curves are The Evil ! (see this post : https://geonet.esri.com/thread/109804). Seems there are mainly created in geodatabases (not shapefiles). . Those curved devils seem to imply integrity problems ahead...(see : https://geonet.esri.com/thread/57456).

Comment: Another info to complete my previous comment : "Shapefiles do not support true curves". So if you create curves in your actual application in a geodatabase, i understand they will have to be transformed later using a densify function, to recreate linear segments and be shp-compatible - or cause problems... But this doesn't answer your question.