# Generating polygons with streets as borders using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, google-maps, geometry-conversion

I have searched online for almost a week and can not find an answer to my issue.

I need to generate polygons from street borders in a given city.

I have downloaded data from openstreetmaps and imported it into QGIS.

Is there a way to generate polygons and use streets as borders?

Comment: Question is duplicate to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85452/make-a-polygon-from-intersecting-lines-in-qgis-using-polygonize-or-similar.  Recommended answer is to use the "Polygonize" tool.

Comment: Check this out http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58245/generate-polygons-from-a-set-of-intersecting-lines

Comment: I think GRASS gives a more comfortable solution for QGIS users (through the GRASS plugin). Import your polylines into GRASS, convert polylines to boundaries, generate centroids and finally clean and build polygon topology.

Answer (score 2):

There's a link [Create polygon layer from polyline layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30765/create-polygon-layer-from-polyline-layer) that might help on how to do this in QGIS.

This post mentions dangling lines (lines that don't form a complete boundary) which may or may not be important to you.

If you are after a single polygon that covers all of your roads (guaranteed) then consider a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

The [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/) gives an [exercise](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/geometry.html?highlight=convex%20hull) that might illuminate.