# Make polygon from area not covered by loaded polygons (like invert selection)

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson, kml

See screenshot, from geojson.io, with a geojson file loaded:
[image]

So how do we make a polygon out of the blank area? Looking for a way which doesn't involve *manually* copying selected sequences of co-ordinates from each enclosing polygon's edge. But if we can automate that, awesome!

Obviously the solution would involve specifying a bounding box limit, so we don't polygon the planet.

Some kind of proximity detection could be a way to go : enlist lines (ie, pair of sequential co-ordinates) which don't have any close-by counterparts in the other polygons loaded. Just an idea.

Guess I'm wishing for an "invert selection" like feature ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One  approach  would  be  to  create  another  layer  with  a  polygon  that  roughly  covers  the  hole  and  then  use  a  geoprocessing  operation, such  as  difference  or  clip  to  remove  the  overlap  and  leave  just  the  jigsaw  piece  you  want. The  extent  of  the  rough-cut polygon  would  limit  the  operation  to  the  region  of  interest.

This might  be  an  approach  in  qgis, I  don't  know  what  program  you  are  using.

Answer (score 1):

Use [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) for this, the functions [`union`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_union.html) and [`erase`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_erase.html) in particular.

Make a `union` of all your polygons (or at least the ones that are within the current viewport), then `erase` the result from the polygon that covers the current viewport. The result will be the inverted selection you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So not completely automated but my answer at for the following questions solves it quickly:
[Connecting polygon accidentally deleted - filling in the gap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139100/connecting-polygon-accidentally-deleted-filling-in-the-gap/139169#139169)